# How can i correctly type an object with typescript with condition on property object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I begin with Typescript and I tried to use an object inside the `if` block. In the `if` I test for the condition - if one property exists and if it's the case I can use it into the `if` block but TS compiler don't seems to understand

```js
type Fish = {
    swim: () => void
}

type Bird = {
    fly: () => void
}

const test = function (pet: Fish | Bird) {
    if ((pet as Fish).swim) {
        pet.swim()
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgZwBZQLxQN4Cgq6ggdzgFsAuKACgEo0A+KANwHs4ATLAXyy1EigCE4AJ1ZpMOPADMANiHLU6jFuy5YAxkwB2CYFGAQdYyQFdNa4HC2VIwcvGRQAPgOGsa2PFDiTKFG1ABDBFhEJCoAOkISdwlPXBtIomJqWKguDiA)

Answer (score 1):

The check

```
if ((pet as Fish).swim)
```

does nothing to help TS infer the type of `pet`, because every Fish has `swim` already. Use `in` to check if the property exists instead, and do it on the `pet`, so that `pet` gets narrowed down to `Fish` and can have `swim` called on it:

```
const test = function (pet: Fish | Bird) {
    if ('swim' in pet) {
        pet.swim();
    }
};
```